# How can I restore Office 2013 shortcuts on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, office-2013-preview

I installed Office 2013 on Windows 8 in Audit Mode. After I finished everything, office works ok, but there is no shortcut for the office programs on the start menu of Windows,I tried to run a Repair but it didn't restore them.

Is there any command that would do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to search for the Office apps you want shortcuts to, either by typing it's name at the Start Screen, or choosing search from the Charms Menu (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

Ignore the fact that I am using Office 2010, it should be the same process for 2013.

[image: Searching for Word]

Right click on the app and a menu will come up at the bottom of the screen, select **Pin to Start**.

[image: Right click menu]

If you want to do them all at once you could search "2013" instead of the name of the specific app.